# Почему не закрашивается фон JMenu? Java

Tags: java, swing

Мне необходимо закрасить фон выделенного пункта JMenu. 
 Пробовал напрямую обратится к объекту и использовать setBackground()- тщетно. Как можно исправить эту ситуацию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]